# Getting df with distribution per group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distribution

I have a dataframe with Reddit data including an author and a subreddit field.
I would like to get, per author, a distribution of how often he/she posts in each subreddit which can be compared to the distribution of other authors.

```
sub_visits = df.groupby('author').subreddit.value_counts()/df.groupby('author').subreddit.count()
```

That line gives me a multi-indexed pandas dataframe with author as the first index. Then all subreddits in which the author was active as second index and finally as values the fraction of their posts which were in that subreddit.

That's good, but I would like to end up with distributions of equal length for each author.

To do this I included all subreddits from the entire df (rather than only those visited by the author), in a dataframe with the authors as rows. Then I fill this with zeros, and then with the values from sub_visits.

This for loop technically works for this.

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(index = df.author.unique(),columns = all_subs)
pdf = pdf.fillna(0)

for idx, df_select in sub_visits.groupby(level=[0, 1]):
            pdf.loc[idx[0],idx[1]] = df_select[0]
```

It is quite slow however, for just filling in values. I wonder if there is a better way to do this? Either creating the distribution, or filling in the values.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for quite a bit I stumbled upon the answer. It is actually fairly simple, but I didn't find it easy to find, so I hope this question might help others with the same problem. Such a distribution (here over 'subreddit' within 'author') matrix within a group in pandas can quickly be gotten with:

```
sub_visits = df.groupby('author').subreddit.value_counts()/df.groupby('author').subreddit.count()
sub_visits = sub_visits.unstack(-1)
sub_visits = sub_visits.fillna(0)
```